# how to redirect clicked link to specific url on mobilescreens

Tags: jquery, redirect, hyperlink

I have a simple link on a website header with class "contact". is it possible to redirect this link on mobile / media screen smaller than 1000px to a specific url when clicked? with jquery / js?

I have no idea if this could work :)

Best

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is entirely possible.

```
$('a.some-link-class').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if ($(window).width() < 1000) window.location = 'http://small-screen-url/';
    else window.location = window.location = 'http://large-screen-url/';
});
```

This code simply checks the width of the window and redirects based off of that condition.